# Unable to find BLE peripherals

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am new on Xcode and I wrote a little bit of code to discover and connect to BLE module (Adafruit Bluefruit LE). However when scanning, nothing is found.
Any help please ?

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    //let BLUEFRUIT_SERVICE = "DFB0"
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var connectedPeripheral : CBPeripheral!



    @IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender.tag)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        centralManager=CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func scanForDevice () {
        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil )
// I also tried with the following line, but I don't understand the use of BLUEFRUIT_SERVICE = "DFB0"
        //        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([CBUUID(string: BLUEFRUIT_SERVICE)], options: nil)

    }

    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("\(peripheral.name!)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //Central Manager delegates

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("central manager did updated started")

        switch(central.state){
        case .PoweredOff:
            print("Power is OFF")
            break

        case .Resetting:
            print("Resetting")
            break

        case .PoweredOn :
            print("Power is ON");
            break

        case.Unauthorized:
            print("Unauthorized")
            break

        case .Unsupported:
            print("Unsupported")
            break

        default:
            print("Unknown")
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: When do you call `scanForDevice`? You should call this in the powered on state

Comment: i tried that option as well, but still nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to see the device when you scan using an application like LightBlue?

I ran into similar problems while trying to connect to a Bluno device.  Feel free to take a look at my code and see if it works for you.  It's currently hard coded to look for two particular Bluno devices, but you should be able to easily change it to connect if it finds the correct one.

https://github.com/FredLoh/BluetoothResearchProject

Try the following code.  Note: You might have to update the device name (currently Bluno), as well as the DF80 and DF81 strings to whatever your device accepts.  You might also have to wire this up correctly to whatever interface you are using.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

  var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
  var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral!



  @IBAction func myButton(sender: UIButton) {
      print(sender.tag)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      centralManager=CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
  }

  func startScanning() {
    print("Started Scanning!")
    //Could add service UUID here to scan for only relevant services
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

func sendMessage() {
    let message = "5"
    let data = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    if terminalChar != nil {
        peripheral!.writeValue(data!,  forCharacteristic: terminalChar, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
    }
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
    print("Value was sent")
}

func discoverDevices() {
    print("discovering devices")
    centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    print("Checking state")
    switch (central.state) {
    case .PoweredOff:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")

    case .PoweredOn:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
        bluetoothAvailable = true;

    case .Resetting:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting")

    case .Unauthorized:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized")

    case .Unknown:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");

    case .Unsupported:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");

    }
    if bluetoothAvailable == true {
        discoverDevices()
    }
}
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    //        print(peripheral)
    let deviceName = "Bluno"
    if let nameOfDeviceFound = peripheral.name {
        if (nameOfDeviceFound == deviceName) {
            print("Discovered \(deviceName)")
            print("")

            print(peripheral)
            // Stop scanning
            self.centralManager.stopScan()
            print("Stopped Scanning")
            // Set as the peripheral to use and establish connection
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            self.peripheral.delegate = self
            self.centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
        else {
            print("NOPE.EXE")
        }
    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Did connect to peripheral.")
    print("")
    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices([CBUUID(string: "DFB0")])
    let state = peripheral.state == CBPeripheralState.Connected ? "yes" : "no"
    print("Connected:\(state)")

}

//    // Check if the service discovered is a valid IR Temperature Service
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
    if(error != nil) {
        print(error?.description)
    }

    for svc in peripheral.services! {
        print("Service \(svc)\n")
        print("Discovering Characteristics for Service : \(svc)")
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([CBUUID(string: "DFB1")], forService: svc as CBService)
    }
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
    if(error != nil) {
        print(error?.description)
    }
    for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
        if characteristic.UUID == CBUUID(string: "DFB1") {
            self.terminalChar = (characteristic as CBCharacteristic)
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: characteristic as CBCharacteristic)

            // Send notification that Bluetooth is connected and all required characteristics are discovered
            print("Found characteristic we were looking for!")
            print(peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(characteristic as CBCharacteristic))

        }
    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
    print("Failed to connect to peripheral.")
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
    print("CONNECTION WAS DISCONNECTED")
}
}
```

Comment: I am able to connect using your program, however unable to send any command. Indeed my BLE need for instance to receive the char 'l' to operate an action, I tried to change the message function but it does not work.

Comment: Hey @Raph you need to change the message function and the didDiscoverPeripheral, the didConnectPeripheral and the didDiscoverServices.  Currently the CBUUID service that I am looking for is 2222.  My guess is that yours is DF81.  Give it a shot and let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am very new on Xcode so I don't really know what to change in the different functions and how to determine the CBUUID...

Comment: Editing my post one sec.  Will post my old bluno code

Comment: Hi, I was able to connect...but still can't send any command :-/ Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hi, I change the fDFB0 to "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e" and I got this in the terminal :  <CBPeripheral: 0x1753a510, identifier = 6091128F-B46D-ED72-45DE-401DA11BB2DC, name = Adafruit Bluefruit LE, state = disconnected>
Stopped Scanning
Did connect to peripheral.

Connected:yes
Service <CBService: 0x176323e0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E>

Discovering Characteristics for Service : <CBService: 0x176323e0, isPrimary = YES, UUID = 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E>. However when change DFB1,I got different services ID but still not able to send command

Comment: I found this UUIDs in the program developped by Adafruit to connect to my bluetooth module...https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvoim3hymtdkah6/UUID.rtf?dl=0

Comment: Hey Raph, give me a few minutes, I'm gonna upload a previous commit that just had the bare bones so you can have clearer code available.

Comment: Hey @Raph give this a shot. https://github.com/FredLoh/BLE-Swift-Base
Open up the .xcworkspace and play around with the settings at the very top until you find which one the correct UUID for the characteristic and peripheral are.